# Java Generic formal parameters

Tags: java, generics

I am implementing a simple `LinkedList` class and I want it to use generics. The class declaration is:

```
public class LinkedList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements List<E> {
```

This is a teaching example, so the `Abstract` parent and the interface are also my own. The problem arises when I realized that to add and maintain sorting, I need a class (E) which is also `Comparable`. I thought I could limit that to just the methods where it actually makes a difference. But based on the comments below, that may be my basic misunderstanding.

Here's the code:

```
  public void addSorted(<E extends Comparable<E>> value) {
    if (front == null || value.compareTo(front.word) <= 0) {
      // insert at front of list
      front = new ListNode<E>(value, front);
    } else {
      // insert in middle of list
      ListNode<E> current = front;
      while (current.next != null && current.next.word.compareTo(value) < 0) {
        current = current.next;
      }
      current.next = new ListNode<E>(value, current.next);
    }
  }
```

It seemed to me that if I never want to call `addSorted` then why should the particular class be limited to E's that implement `Comparable`? Or is there a totally different way to do it, with a generic analog to instances?

Comment: That's not the correct syntax. It should either be `public <E extends Comparable<E>> void addSorted(E value)` or just `public void addSorted(E value)` if `E` is a type parameter of the class. We need more information.

Comment: Neither can we if you don't describe the problem.

Comment: You should imrpove your question. Is there a compilation error? Is there is, which one? Is there a runtime error instead?

Answer (score 2):

Consider what happens if you are able to call both `add` and `addSorted` on a `LinkedList` instance:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add("c"); list.add("a");
list.addSorted("b");
```

In this case, where do you expect `"b"` to be inserted into a list `["c", "a"]`:

- It is lexicographically before `"c"`, so it could be inserted at the start, yielding `["b", "c", "a"]`;
- It is lexicographically after `"a"`, so it could be inserted at the end, yielding `["c", "a", "b"]`;

But neither list is really "sorted" afterwards.

To me, the only obvious way to resolve this ambiguity is to force *all* adds to be done in a sorted way. This implies that you should create a subclass of `LinkedList`, `SortedLinkedList`, which overrides the `LinkedList.add` method:

```
class SortedLinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>> extends LinkedList<E> {
  void add(E element) {
    // The implementation of addSorted.
  }
}
```

---

In general, the way I would handle methods that should only available for certain generic types is to do it using a method which accepts an instance of the class as the first parameter, outside the definition of the class (or inside the definition of the class, but defined as `static`). This means that it's not part of the interface of the class, so it's not present for classes with incompatible generic types.

For example, if you wanted to add a `sort` method to sort `LinkedList`s, this is obviously only sensible for ones with `Comparable` elements:

```
static <E extends Comparable<E>> void sort(LinkedList<E> list) {
  // ...
}
```

For example:

```
LinkedList<String> strList = new LinkedList<>();
// ... Add elements.
sort(strList); // OK.

LinkedList<Object> objList = new LinkedList<>();
// ... Add elements.
sort(objList); // Compiler error - Object is not a valid bound.
```

Comment: Excellent response. A few followups: Let's say I wanted to make all uses of LinkedList<> require a subclass of Comparable, would the proper class declaration be: public class LinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>> extends AbstractList<E> implements List<E> {? That's what I have and it compile and it seems to work correctly. Even though the List<E> interfaces does not mention Comparable and so on. Secondly, I suppose one might (I wouldn't) make "addSorted" detect that the list was not already sort it, and then sort it first. A boolean could track whether the list was already sorted.

Comment: 1) Yes, that's correct. The `<E extends Comparable<E>>` declares the type variable with its constraints; the subsequent `<E>` is simply using it (just like you only need `String something` to declare it, but `something` to use it).

Comment: 2) Well, I suppose you could, but it'd get a bit messy.